# react-bootstrap-typeahead problems using defaultSelected and selected

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

When I use the options defaultSelected, or selected, in my Typeahead I can't seem to be able to use the backspace to remove the input and change the listing.

It seems to get some kind of next array selection instead of overwriting the value.

At some point it seems to go through all values in the options, then will actually start overwriting the input value and component works fine from then on.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post code examples?

Comment: <Typeahead  bsSize="sm"
                            defaultSelected = {props.options.slice(selectedIndex)}
                            clearButton
                            labelKey="roomNumber"
                            options={props.options}
                            placeholder={props.placeholder}
                            name={props.nameId}
                          />

Comment: Trying to basically use the component as is.  I ended up putting on the clear button.    I had thought it might be my component re-rendering and causing problems, but I took out any onInputChange or onBlur changes that set state.  It still happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
defaultSelected={props.options.slice(selectedIndex, selectedIndex + 1)}
```

The behavior you describe is due partly to how you're using `slice` and partly to a bug with the component. From the `slice` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> If end is omitted, slice extracts through the end of the sequence (arr.length).

Because you only provide the start index, your `defaultSelected` array has multiple items. However, the single-select component doesn't automatically truncate the number of selections (this is being fixed in an upcoming version), so hitting backspace deletes the current selection and displays the next one, and so on until there are no more items in the `selected` array.